# Cassandra cluster: could not reach linear scalability

Tags: cassandra, scalability

I've configured a simple cluster using two PC with identical spec:

```
  cpu core i5
   RAM: 8GB ddr3
   Disk: 1TB 5400rpm
   Network: 1 G (I've test it with iperf, it really is!)
```

using the common configs described in many sites including datastax itself:

```
cluster_name: 'MyCassandraCluster'
num_tokens: 256
seed_provider:
  - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
    parameters:
         - seeds: "192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2"
listen_address:
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
```

Running stress tool:

```
cassandra-stress write n=1000000 -rate threads=1000 -mode native cql3 -node 192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2
```

Over each node it shows 39 K writes/seconds, but running the same stress tool command on cluster of both nodes shows 45 K writes/seconds. I've done all the tuning mentioned by apache and datastax.
There are many use cases on the net proving Cassandra linear Scalability So what is wrong with my cluster?

Comment: too many variables are in place - what network is used, what storage type (HDD vs SSD), did you clean data from previous runs of stress tool, etc.

Comment: i assumed that,linear scaling means throughput of cluster = number of nodes * throughput of node (assume having identical nodes), anyway i updated the question

Comment: I assume that you did first testing against the same cluster but did use only one IP as `-node` parameter? This parameter specify the nodes that will be used to handle the client's traffic (so-called coordinator nodes, but this depends on settings), not the nodes that actually own the data. In your case, it looks like you saturate the single coordinator node, and get benefit from adding another one. There are multiple good articles on correct performance testing, like this: https://medium.com/linode-cube/load-testing-apache-cassandra-parsing-latency-throughput-results-part-1-of-3-1c0712166e40

Comment: I'm using all nodes in -node, still the same

Comment: As I mentioned, by specifying only one IP in `-node` parameter you don't test one server, you test whole cluster but connection goes through one node. If you want to test linear scalability, you need first setup single-node cluster, test it, then add another node & test again.

Comment: I tested exactly as you said, 1. started with cluster containing a single node got 39 K Ops/S (i run tests > 5 times), 2. added an identical node to existing cluster got 45 K Op/s (expected > 70 K Op/s)